# No puedo usar funciones, variables de otro archivo js

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hola a todos necesito de su ayuda estoy creando una validacion de formulario en jquery para esto estoy haciéndolo en dos archivos js:

1. validacion-form.js
2. ajax.js

El primero con una función para validar y el segundo con una función para enviar los datos del formulario usando ajax.
El problema es que quiero usar la función del archivo ajax.js dentro del archivo validacion-form.js

```
//ajax.js
$(document).ready(function() {
function SendForm(){
//Codigo
})
```

/**********************/

```
//validacion-form.js
        $(document).ready(function() {
        function Validar(){
        //Codigo
        SendForm();//Aqui llamo la funcion dentro de validacion-form.js
        })
```

Me aparece el siguiente error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: SendForm is not defined

Pienso que tal vez sea por $(document).ready(function(){}) pero si borro esto no puedo usar algunas de las funciones de mi código.
Necesito su ayuda por favor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tú función SendForm no es global, está en un ámbito no accesible por cualquier otra función que no se encuentre mínimo en el mismo ámbito que tu función, por lo tanto tu otro fichero en tu función Validar no lo encontrará.

¿Solución?

Declara las funciones qué necesites entre ficheros de manera global (fuera del ready de jQuery).